# Custom Sheet : can't click buttons

Tags: cocoa, nspanel

I used this source http://www.cats.rwth-aachen.de/library/programming/cocoa

to create my custom sheet.

I created a `NSPanel` object in existing .xib file and connected with `IBOutlet`

My source code:

**.h**

```
@interface MainDreamer : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> 
{    
 ...
 NSPanel *newPanel;
}
...
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPanel *newPanel;
```

**.m**

```
@dynamic newPanel;
...

//this method is wired with button on main window and calls a sheet
- (IBAction)callPanel:(id)sender
{
    [NSApp beginSheet:newPanel
       modalForWindow:[self window] modalDelegate:self
       didEndSelector:@selector(myPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
          contextInfo: nil]; //(__bridge void *)[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0]
}

//this method is wired with cancel and ok buttons on the panel
- (IBAction)endWorkPanel:(id)sender
{
    [newPanel orderOut:self];
    [NSApp endSheet:newPanel returnCode:([sender tag] == 9) ? NSOKButton : NSCancelButton];
} 

//closing a sheet
- (void)myPanelDidEnd:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(int)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (returnCode == NSCancelButton) return;
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

So `callPanel` works fine, sheet appears but I can't interact with controls on the sheet (with buttons). They don't react on a click (even visually).

Where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, I forgot about

```
[newDreamPanel close];
```

in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method. I wrote it because I wanted the panel to not appear when main window launches.

In fact, the `Visible At Launch` panel's property should be activated in IB. The `close` method works too, but side effect is that all controls become unable on the panel.